# Error connecting to database in Node

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I was working on a project using Node with a PostgresDB. Everything was fine, but then it starts throwing an "Error: connect ECONNREFUSED". I didn't change anything regarding my DB connection, so I decided to restart the machine, and the error was gone. Does anyone knows what can cause this error?

Comment: Was the database a separate server machine on running on your development machine?

Comment: It is running in the same machine (localhost).

Answer (score 1):

the db process wasn't running. When you restart the machine the db was restarted as well.

Comment: Querying a database using pgAdmin is different from using Node? Because I did a query using pgAdmin and it worked, but using Node failed.